# Windows 10 phone How add Checkbox to the ListView

Tags: c#, checkbox, windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I want add Text to ListView element when i press button:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        listView.Items.Add(textBox.Text);        

    }
```

It works but i got:

```
Element1
Element2
Element3
```

But i want to see something like:

```
[]Element1
[]Element2
```

Where [ ] is checkbox :)

My xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="406" Margin="10,224,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="340" />
```

I don't see option CheckBoxes True/False in my xaml Properties

Answer (score 0):

**XAML**

- Modify the listView item template to add your custom layout.
- Add a data binding to the set the text

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="340">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel>
                <CheckBox/>
                <Label Content="{Binding Text}"/>
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Code Behind**

- declare this class somewhere

```
public class Row
{
    private string text;

    public Row (string text)
    {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public string Text
    {
         get { return text; }
         set { text = value; }
    }
 }
```

Add this code to the constructor of the code associated with the xaml

```
ObservableCollection<Row> list = new ObservableCollection<Row>();
listView.ItemsSource = list;
```

How to add items/text to the listView

```
list.Add(new Row("Hello"));
list.Add(new Row("World"));
```

Hope this helps!